# Core Data Inverse RelationShip

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am creating Travel guide app using core data. I have 4 entities CITY ,RESTAURANTS ,
HOTEL AND FAMOUS PLACES. City is connected with all other entity because one city may have number of restaurants , hotels and places. City entity has 3 attribute Name ,Image ,Description. I am able to display list restaurants of selected city.In Restaurant Entity I have 4 attribute Name, Description ,Address and phone no..Now I want to show
this attribute detail of selected restaurant(of selected city) in next view.But how can I access restaurant description in next view..
Here is my code.

```
     - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        NSMutableArray *restaurants = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[city.cityTorestaurants allObjects]];





        NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor  = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nameDescriptor,nil];
        [restaurants sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [hotels sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [self setArrayOfRestaurants:restaurants];
        [restaurants release];
        [nameDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    }

    //set up cell


    NSLog(@"For Restaurants List");
    Restaurants *restaurants = [arrayOfRestaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = restaurants.Name;

return cell; 
}
```

cityTorestaurants and restaurantTocity is relationship in core data..
Help Please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RestaurantViewController create a property `Restaurant* currentRestaurant`
in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`of the CityViewController set the property with `self.restaurantVC.currentRestaurant = [arrayOfRestaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Thank you very much ...I made a very silly mistake..I was writing self.restaurantVC.currentRestaurant = [arrayOfRestaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; after self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller... :P